# Variance pooling when sample size is a predictor

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, pooling

Suppose that I am building a hierarchical model of performance and the data is hierarchically structured (e.g., multiple customers rating a single salesperson). I might want to use variance pooling in this situation to allow individuals who have not had many customers yet borrow information from those who have had more customers. Then again, those with fewer customers may have less experience, and may generate fewer leads because they are poor quality salespeople in general. Here, the sample size is correlated with one or more possible predictors. How to account for this in hierarchical models, especially Bayesian ones? Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, are you working within a specific framework, like JAGS or STAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to just treat the number of customers as an extra response/outcome variable? So a salseperson $i$s quality $q_i$ predict his/her ratings $r_{ij}$  and number of customers $n_i$: Like this:

$$ r_{ij} \sim \mathrm{Norm}(q_i, \sigma_i) \\
n_i  \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda_i) \\
log(\lambda_i) \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot q_i$$

Where $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are parameters in the Poission regression. It would then still be possible to put an hierarchical  prior on all the $q_i$s.

$$q_i \sim \mathrm{Norm}(M,S)$$

The use of the Poisson distribution and the Normal distribution above are purely provisional as I don't know what your data looks like. Also if the salespeople have been active for different amounts of time you would have to include this information in the Poisson regression.

For full disclosure I should also say that I haven't' tested this solution so I'm not 100% it makes sense, but perhaps it can spur others to come up with something better. :)

*Edit 1:* So I ran this model using JAGS and R. Code and output below. I'm pretty sloppy with both the distributions (are ratings that normal? are number of customers really Poisson?) and with priors, but anyway. First the model without taking account of the number of ratings. Here is made up data:

```
person rating
     1      5
     2      4
     2      7
     2      5
     2      9
     2      8
     3      4
     3      6
     4      8
     4      9
     4      6
     4      9
     4      7
     4      8
     5      4
     5      1
```

The model in JAGS and R:

```
ms <- "model{
for(j in 1:length(rating)) {
  rating[j] ~ dnorm(skill[person[j]], 1 / (sigma*sigma))
}

for(i in 1:length(no_ratings)) {
  skill[i] ~ dnorm(mu_skill, 1 / (sigma_skill*sigma_skill))

}

sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
beta_0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
beta_1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
mu_skill ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
sigma_skill ~ dunif(0, 100)
}"

m <- jags.model(textConnection(ms), list(person = d$person, rating = d$rating, no_ratings = table(d$person)), n.chains=3)
s <- coda.samples(m, c("skill", "beta_0", "beta_1", "sigma", "mu_skill", "sigma_skill"), n.iter=10000, thin=5)
summary(s)

##                Mean     SD Naive SE Time-series SE
## beta_0      -0.0973 31.453  0.40605        0.40605
## beta_1      -0.1863 31.835  0.41099        0.40524
## mu_skill     5.5356  1.659  0.02142        0.02255
## sigma        1.9069  0.478  0.00617        0.00802
## sigma_skill  2.7880  2.081  0.02686        0.04628
## skill[1]     5.2788  1.522  0.01965        0.01988
## skill[2]     6.4508  0.820  0.01058        0.01114
## skill[3]     5.2266  1.197  0.01545        0.01756
## skill[4]     7.4901  0.809  0.01045        0.01247
## skill[5]     3.4765  1.471  0.01899        0.02827
```

Then adding the number of customers as a outcome variable (not as a predictor):

```
ms <- "model{
  for(j in 1:length(rating)) {
    rating[j] ~ dnorm(skill[person[j]], 1 / (sigma*sigma))
  }

  for(i in 1:length(no_ratings)) {
    no_ratings[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
    lambda[i] <- exp(beta_0 + beta_1 * skill[i])
    skill[i] ~ dnorm(mu_skill, 1 / (sigma_skill*sigma_skill))

  }

  sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
  beta_0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  beta_1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  mu_skill ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  sigma_skill ~ dunif(0, 100)
}"

m <- jags.model(textConnection(ms), list(person = d$person, rating = d$rating, no_ratings = table(d$person)), n.chains=3)
s <- coda.samples(m, c("skill", "lambda", "beta_0", "beta_1", "sigma", "mu_skill", "sigma_skill"), n.iter=10000, thin=5)

summary(s)

##              Mean    SD Naive SE Time-series SE
## beta_0      -1.061 1.579  0.02038        0.10793
## beta_1       0.367 0.250  0.00323        0.01728
## lambda[1]    2.222 1.059  0.01367        0.03161
## lambda[2]    4.078 1.429  0.01845        0.02115
## lambda[3]    2.509 1.037  0.01339        0.02444
## lambda[4]    5.501 2.078  0.02683        0.05594
## lambda[5]    1.752 0.966  0.01247        0.03602
## mu_skill     5.473 1.610  0.02078        0.02225
## sigma        1.865 0.443  0.00571        0.00697
## sigma_skill  2.669 2.137  0.02759        0.05634
## skill[1]     4.712 1.306  0.01687        0.02302
## skill[2]     6.565 0.721  0.00930        0.01124
## skill[3]     5.101 1.023  0.01321        0.01815
## skill[4]     7.451 0.736  0.00950        0.01579
## skill[5]     3.723 1.323  0.01708        0.03668
```

Notice how the skill parameters changed. For example person 1 got a lower skill assessment than person 3 due to having only one customer while in the first model it was the other way around.

*Edit 2:*

An alternative idea would to use the number of rating as a predictor *on the group level*. That is, allow the group prior to differ depending on the number of ratings like in the following model (again, the distributions used here are placeholders as I don't know your data):

$$ r_{ij} \sim \mathrm{Norm}(q_i, \sigma_i) \\
q_i \sim \mathrm{Norm}(M_i,S) \\
M_i \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot log(n_i) \\
$$

Comment: Yes, simply adding the sample size as a predictor had occurred to me but I wondered if there was something fancier. In addition, I would potentially need to deal with the colinearity between experience and number of customers, which is likely correlated. I will await some other answers but definitely upvoting yours.

Comment: I've added some code. My first suggestion was to include number of ratings, not as a predictor but as a response/outcome variable. I've added a second suggestion where the number of ratings is included as apredictor on the "group level".

Comment: Oh sorry I misread! I will try both options (add as predictor and add as new response variable). I will make sure to examine my data beforehand to see what distributions are appropriate. FYI I will use STAN